# Perl, specify a regular expression for special variable $/

Tags: perl

I have a CSV file with text in them which has new line breaks in it. For example

```
1,b,hello
world,x
2,a,hello

mars,y
```

To read it all in a row at a time, I would like to specify a regular expression for the $/ special variable. Any suggestions on how I could do it?

My thinking is, if I put in something like "(x|y)\n" for my special variable it should capture the cases where the line ends with an x or y along with a new line.

Thanks

Comment: Is the number of fields per line consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a regex for $/.  However, if the file isn't too big, you can read the whole thing into a scalar and split on the regex.

`@records = split /(x|y)\n/, $data;`

Comment: Quoth [perlvar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#$RS): "The value of `$/` is a string, not a regex. awk has to be better for something"

Answer (score 3):

There is no general way of separating such a file into records because it is impossible to tell whether a line from the file is more of the current record or the start of a new one.

However if you can assume

- There are always the same number of fields in a record
- The data in the fields never contains commas
- The last field of the record is never split across lines

then you can simply accumulate lines from the file until you have a sufficient number of fields

This program demonstrates the principle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $record= <>) {
  $record .= <> until $record =~ tr/,// == 3;
  print ">> $record\n";
}
```

**output**

```
>> 1,b,hello
world,x

>> 2,a,hello

mars,y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own sub to read one dataset at at time:

```
 sub readDataSet {
   my $buffer = '';
   local $/ = "\n";
   $buffer .= <STDIN> until $buffer =~ /(x|y)\n$/;
   return $buffer;
 }

 my $nextRow = readDataSet();
```

This will return a whole row. I can do this because your Regexp ends with a constant part. There are several variations to this sub:

1. Read from any filehandle:

   ```
   sub readDataSet {
     my ($filehandle) = @_;
     my $buffer = "";
     $buffer .= <$filehandle> until $buffer =~ /(x|y)\n$/;
     return $buffer;
   }

   open my $fh, "<", $filename or die;
   my $nextRow = readDataSet($fh);
   ```
2. Construct an anonymous sub that does the reading. The Filehandle is provided only once in the constructor sub. This is a bit object-orientish.

   ```
   sub newDataSetReader {
     my ($filehandle) = @_;
     return sub {
       my $buffer = '';
       local $/ = "\n";
       $buffer .= <$filehandle> until $buffer =~ /(x|y)\n$/;
       return $buffer;
     };
   }

   open my $fh, "<", $filename or die;
   my $reader = newDataSetReader($fh);
   my $nextRow = $reader->();
   ```

   I prefer this last solution, but it only makes sense if you read from multiple files.

When you read via a sub, you can easily insert debugging hooks or pre-filter the data, e.g. splitting the row into the fields and returning an array instead of a single string.